# How to add a token when I use the GET method in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qtnetwork, qnetworkreply

I would like to add a token in my GET request in C++/Qt.

This is my GET / download method :

```
QNetworkReply* DownloadManager::doDownload(const QUrl &url)
{
    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    QNetworkReply *reply = m_manager.get(request); // m_manager is a QNetworkAcessManager

    return reply;
}
```

Comment: thanks . it 's ok. you can write your answer. I will valid it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tokens are sent as part of the request header, so for that case we use the [`setRawHeader()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkrequest.html#setRawHeader) method:

> **void QNetworkRequest::setRawHeader(const QByteArray &headerName, const
>   QByteArray &headerValue)**
>
> Sets the header headerName to be of value headerValue. If headerName
>   corresponds to a known header (see QNetworkRequest::KnownHeaders), the
>   raw format will be parsed and the corresponding "cooked" header will
>   be set as well.

In the case of the token we use the following:

```
request.setRawHeader(QByteArray("Authorization"), QByteArray("Token your_token"));
```